# How do I make controls autosizing in Qt designer?

Tags: java, user-interface, qt, qt-jambi

I'm using Qt Jambi 4.4 for a project I'm working on (and designing the windows in the Qt Designer eclipse plugin).  One of the windows I'd like to use is a preview window which is basically just a window with a QWebView on it.  How can I make it so that the QWebView resizes as the window does?  I've set the sizePolicy to expanding for both Horizontal and Vertical position.  What else do I need to do?

(also bear in mind that I'm a newbie to both Java and eclipse and need to be talked to in stupid people terms on both of those subjects)

**UPDATE**

Just to illustrate the point, here are a couple of screenshots (I've made the window background bright just to illustrate my point):

[alt text http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/2103/screenshot2oi7.jpg](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/2103/screenshot2oi7.jpg)

[alt text http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/6250/screenshot1mz9.jpg](http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/6250/screenshot1mz9.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Jambi, but with Qt Designer just give the background the focus and then apply a layout from the toolbar. Then the main widget will get resized by that layout manager -- if you don't add that layout manager you'll get the widget resizing but the contents staying at their old positions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used qt-jambi, but if it is anything like Qt in C++ or PyQt, the QWebView would resize automatically as the window size changes. As far as I know, setting size policies/ expansion factors, adding QSpacerItem objects etc. is only necessary if the sizing behavior is not working right. Just laying it out using an appropriate layout within the preview window should be sufficient. Do let me know if I have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the QWebView in a layout, that it will follow the change in its "container". For using layout with Qt Designer, refer to http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/designer-layouts.html

Answer (score 1):

From Qt Designer docs:

> The form's top level layout can be set by clearing the selection
>   (click the left mouse button on the form itself) and applying a
>   layout. A top level layout is necessary to ensure that your widgets
>   will re-size correctly when its window is re-sized.